# Error in Laravel 8 [ Argument 2 passed ] with command [php artisan make:controller Admin\HomeController]

Tags: php, laravel

I am following a Youtube course, the teacher asks to integrate the AdminLTE template in this video: https://youtu.be/r8RKayPtijc

**The problem** arises once I run the command:

> php artisan make:controller Admin\HomeController

The console responds to me:

> In UrlGenerator.php line 120:
>
> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given,
>
> called in ...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 65

[See console photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHXpI.png)

I already tried:

- I investigated in the comments of the YouTube video to see if someone else happened to him but apparently it is only me.
- I looked into the error on Google but did not find anything similar to my error.
- Create a new Laravel project and verify that the command: php artisan make: controller Admin \ HomeController works and correctly created the folder and its respective file.
- Take the vendor \ laravel \ framework \ src \ Illuminate \ Routing \ RoutingServiceProvider.php file and replace it with mine.
- I reversed the code that the video asked to do.

Nothing worked for me, waiting for a prompt response to know how to correct this in future projects.

Comment: the command is `php artisan make:controller Admin\HomeController`, i suggest you copy paste it. Never change the files in the `vendor` folder. I suggest that you start from a fresh install, you might have errors in your file, especialy the routing files (web.php ....)

Comment: Add your `web.php`

Comment: I think it's not problem with your command. Would you run simple commands like `php artisan serve` and tell me the output? It may fail due to this error

Comment: As @MohammadMirsafaei mentioned, the artisan command may not be the actual problem. It has probably got to do with the changes that you have tried causing this error. Confirm if this error is happing with the above artisan command or any artisan command on your laravel project.